# How to launch the URL in same tab

Tags: c++, winapi, firefox

i am trying to open the URL.. if i try this it will open in new tab i want it to do in the same tab how can i do that

```
 ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", "file:///C:/Users/pawws014/Desktop/error.html/", NULL, NULL,  SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change the [Browser.link.open_external settings](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_external) in Firefox to open the link in the current window.

It is a setting in [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_%3a_FAQs_%3a_About%3aconfig_Entries).